# Google iOS API Auth2 Login blank screen

Tags: ios, xcode, google-api, youtube-api

For the life of me, I can not figure this out.  I followed the instructions on this blog http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/ to help me set up sharing videos on youtube.  However, before I am able to share videos, I need the user to be able to log into google and get permission.  However only a blank screen pops up.  I noticed in the errors that I get this error "missing GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.nib".

```
NSLog(@"PostVideoToYoutube");
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kMyscope
                                                                 clientID:kMyClientID
                                                             clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                         keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                         finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

    [ITVC presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Can anyone please point me to the right direction on why the Google login page is not showing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old question but heres the answer for anyone stuck:

While you may have the GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib file in your projects directory you, need to add it to 'Compile Sources'.

Click on your project settings > 'Build Phases' tab and click the '+' icon under compile sources. Here add 'GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib'.

Build, run, happy days.

Comment: No worries, if you found this the solution be sure to tick it so others can see it answered your question :)

Comment: Even if GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib is in the GData.xcodeproj (which it should be) you still need to add it to your project. (Right click in project navigator -> Add new files...) This is because that .xib needs to be in your projects bundle. For me it wouldn't work if I dragged the .xib from GData.xcodeproj into Compile Sources in the Build Phases tab. The clue for me was when I tried to right click the .xib in GData to add it to my project's target and it wasn't an option. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It worked for me. But one question, is there any guidelines about this in the Google's official documentations?

Answer (score 2):

the following are the steps I used to get it to work.  I am referencing the libGDataTouchStaticLib.a and GData project in my project.

1. in XCode, control-click on a Group under which you want the .xib
2. select Add Files to "My Project"...
3. select the "GData Sources/Common/Optional/OAuth2/iOS/GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib" and click Add.  The .xib will be added to your project's Copy Bundle Resources
4. Clean, Build, Run, Test.

Thanks to @DexCurl's answer, as it got me going in the right direction.

Comment: I also got this to work by adding it to Copy Bundle Resources for the main project, not Compile Sources. It would have been cleaner if the GTL static library would also create a bundle target which would contain this resource. We would still be required to add it to Copy Bundle Resources in our main project, but at least it would be more obvious that there was something that needed to be added.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the view is, as you guess, missing it's nib file.

You need to add the `GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib` (not xib, not nib
extension; while they are called "nib" files, they long ago were
changed to an XML format, and so the actual extension is xib).

The blog post you reference seem to be missing that step.
See the GTM instructions here:
http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Adding_the_Controllers_to_Your_Project

Comment: I see the GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib in my directory.  Its in "GData Sources/Common/Optional/OAuth2/IOS".